# Query all Google Sheets data from Google Drive?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

How can I query all Dates from all Google Sheets in my Google Drive?
As far as I know, I can do multiple `query` for all the sheets using `importrange`, however, I have over 100 Google Sheets:

```
={query(importrange("URL","'TX'!A:U"), "Select * where Col4 contains '"&D2&"'",
0),query(importrange("URL","'TX'!A:U"), "Select * where Col4 contains '"&D2&"'",
0),query(importrange("URL","'TX'!A:U"), "Select * where Col4 contains '"&D2&"'",
0),query(importrange("URL","'TX'!A:U"), "Select * where Col4 contains '"&D2&"'",
0),query(importrange("URL","'TX'!A:U"), "Select * where Col4 contains '"&D2&"'",
0)}
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Welcome. Are you doing this longhand already? I am concerned about the impact on your spreadsheet of a query containing 100 `importrange` queries, each with 21 columns of data. Even if we assume for a moment that the formula can be easily done, what will be the effect on the recalculation rate?

Comment: Does this question [Google Sheets - Using IMPORTRANGE with a variable number of rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138569/196152) help?